# Host Integration server 2016 and BizTalk Arabic text support

Tags: db2, biztalk, arabic, biztalk-2016

I am using BizTalk server 2016 and Host integration server 2016 to connect to DB2 and retrieve the data

Everything is working fine except when text in DB2 is Arabic BizTalk is receiving ??? in data.

I did try this [IBM Arabic Language Problem (Host integration Server)](https://uatif.wordpress.com/2009/05/26/ibm-arabic-language-problem-host-integration-server/)  but no use.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Can you give us some more information on how you connect? What are the DB2 adapter settings for example?

Comment: Hi, I am connecting using HIS DB2 adapter for receive port and in data source I have mentioned CCSID=20420;PC Code Page=1256 (which are for retrieving Arabic text) but still its failing. Any suggestion will be great help for me

Comment: Is it only Arabic characters that are a problem or any extended character?  Chinese for instance.

Comment: was able to solve this it was not HIS problem but problem with way i was reading message in pipeline component